# Is it secure to put a callback URL in a URL's query string?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, authorization, pci-compliance

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC5 web app.  Say a user's session times out and they must go to a login screen to authenticate again, then be redirected back to the URL they came from.  Is it good practice to put the return (callback) URL in the query string of the login URL?

Does anybody know about the PCI compliance for this?  I remember going through PCI training and they mentioned callback URLs, but I can't remember if this follows compliance or not.  If not, is there a more secured way in ASP.NET MVC to pass a callback URL?  I'm currently not using any Auth/Auth libraries, just doing all authentication by hand using cookie management...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not just use an HTTP POST with the URL in the login request somewhere?

Comment: Sounds good. However, I'm making the call to the login screen from a dialog box in jQuery.  Is there a way to make a full-page HTTP POST with data directly from javascript?

Comment: Do you have access to alter the login screen code?

Comment: Sorry for the psudocode.

You would do something like post to the page with only the URL defined.  If the login box code detects that only the URL is posted, it displays the login box.  When the login box posts, it posts the userid, password and URL.  If the authentication succeeds, the end-user is sent to the posted URL.

Comment: Thanks Tripp.  But, there is no login box.  The user has a dialog box open, then sits on it overnight.  The next day he/she tries to post using the dialog box.  The login page requires a full-page GET.  I just had to validate the return url wasn't foreign as Daniel's answer states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like any other piece of code, it can be or not PCI compliant depending if is implemented properly / securely.

For example:

```
private ActionResult RedirectReturnUrl(string returnUrl)
{
    return Redirect(returnUrl);
}
```

If you use the above piece of code to redirect to the `returnUrl` in the query string, you'll be vulnerable to [open redirection attacks](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/preventing-open-redirection-attacks).

However, you can make this *secure* if you ensure the `returnUrl` is local to the current `host`:

```
private ActionResult RedirectToLocal(string returnUrl)
{
   if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
   {
     return Redirect(returnUrl);
   }

   return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

See [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/preventing-open-redirection-attacks) for more details

Comment: Great! Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for.  The article helped too.